# Is there a "multi-value text edit control" available?

Tags: windows, winapi, properties, controls

Some Windows file properties are multi-value (like the "Categories" property, for example), so when editing them in Explorer's details pane, they'll use a "[multi-value text edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/propdesc-schema-editcontrol?redirectedfrom=MSDN)."  Basically it has special behavior in the way it advances the cursor, separates values using semi-colons, etc. Is that type of edit control available for general use outside of the details pane?

Comment: It's not provided by the OS. You might be able to find a third-party component, otherwise you'll have to implement it yourself (via subclassing the edit control, or a whole custom control).

Comment: So just to make sure I'm on the right track, for example, I'll do something like: trap the backspace key, get the window text, check if the text ends in a semi-colon, if so, remove the entire last item in the list, etc.?

Comment: Actually, I think it'll require setting some flags to keep state.  I know I'll also have to trap the semi-colon key and implement special behavior for that too.